# Как узнать в PHP состояние "checkbox" на прошлой странице

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Как узнать в PHP состояние "checkbox" на предыдущей странице?

Имеется код:

```html
<label class="container">Вывоз мусора - 100 
     <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox"><i>$. чел</i>
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Задайте name аттрибут
2) Нечекнутый чекбокс отправляться на сервер вроде как не будет.

Вам видимо нужна форма

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
<label class="container">Вывоз мусора - 100 
 <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="your_checkbox"><i>$. чел</i>
 <span class="checkmark"></span>
```

И в `php` поймаете ее в глобальном массиве $_POST

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['your_checkbox']);
```

Comment: Типо if(isset($_POST['checkbox2']){}